# Music notes longer than a maxima

Tags: theory, notation

I have been studying music since now, and since, I have been wondering if there was a note longer than a maxima. I know a dotted maxima, but what other note is longer than that? That was the most important question about music I wanted to know the answer to.
But "Maxima" comes from the word "maximal" so maybe it's the longest music note except for a dotted maxima.